# Partial encapsulation of OpenCL causing segmentation fault, code sample included

Tags: c++, c++11, opencl

This completely baffles me. Two sets of code that should logically be the same, one crashes only on a GPU while both run fine on a CPU. Here is the test code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <CL/cl.hpp>

class Device
{
public:
    cl::Platform platform_;
    cl::Device device_;
    cl::Context context_;
    cl::CommandQueue queue_;

    Device( void ) : platform_()
                   , device_()
                   , context_()
                   , queue_() {}

    Device(int32_t platform, int32_t device) : platform_()
                                             , device_()
                                             , context_()
                                             , queue_()
    {
        std::vector<cl::Platform> platforms;
        cl::Platform::get(&platforms);
        platform_ = platforms[platform];

        std::vector<cl::Device> devices;
        platform_.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, &devices);
        device_ = devices[device];

        cl_context_properties properties[3] = {
            CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM,
            (cl_context_properties)(platform_)(),
            0
        };

        cl_int clErr = CL_SUCCESS;
        context_ = cl::Context(device_, properties, NULL, NULL, &clErr);
        queue_ = cl::CommandQueue(context_,device_,0,&clErr);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Device device(0,0);

    cl::Program::Sources source;
    std::string src =
    "__kernel void Pointless(uint total, __global uint *data)"\
    "{"\
    "   uint perStream=total/get_global_size(0);"\
    "   __global uint *dest=data+get_global_id(0)*perStream;"\
    "   for(uint i=0;i<perStream;i++)"\
    "       dest[i] = 1;"\
    "}";

    source.push_back({src.c_str(),src.length()});

    cl_int clErr = CL_SUCCESS;
    cl::Program program = cl::Program(device.context_,source,&clErr);
    if (clErr != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create program: " << clErr << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    clErr = program.build({device.device_});
    if(clErr != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to build program: " << clErr << std::endl;
        std::cerr << program.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG>(device.device_) << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    uint32_t samples = 16*256;
    cl::make_kernel<cl_uint,cl::Buffer> Pointless(cl::Kernel(program,"Pointless"));
    cl::Buffer device_samples(device.context_,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,sizeof(cl_uint)*samples);
    Pointless(cl::EnqueueArgs(device.queue_, cl::NDRange(16)), samples, device_samples).wait();

    std::vector<cl_uint> host_samples(samples);
    device.queue_.enqueueReadBuffer(device_samples,CL_TRUE,0,sizeof(cl_uint)*samples,host_samples.data());

    for (auto x: host_samples)
        std::cout << x;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The above seems to fail: I get a segmentation fault on `enqueueReadBuffer`. More interesting, it only fails on the GPU (Intel P4000). The CPU (i3 3xxx) runs it without issue (change `CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU` to `CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU` to test on the CPU).

Now the code below works fine with both device types.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <CL/cl.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::vector<cl::Platform> platforms;
    cl::Platform::get(&platforms);
    cl::Platform platform = platforms[0];

    std::vector<cl::Device> devices;
    platform.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, &devices);
    cl::Device device = devices[0];

    cl_context_properties properties[3] = {
        CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM,
        (cl_context_properties)(platform)(),
        0
    };

    cl_int clErr = CL_SUCCESS;
    cl::Context context(device, properties, NULL, NULL, &clErr);

    cl::CommandQueue queue(context,device,0,&clErr);

    cl::Program::Sources source;
    std::string src =
    "__kernel void Pointless(uint total, __global uint *data)"\
    "{"\
    "   uint perStream=total/get_global_size(0);"\
    "   __global uint *dest=data+get_global_id(0)*perStream;"\
    "   for(uint i=0;i<perStream;i++)"\
    "       dest[i] = 1;"\
    "}";

    source.push_back({src.c_str(),src.length()});

    cl::Program program = cl::Program(context,source,&clErr);

    clErr = program.build({device});
    if(clErr != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        std::cerr << program.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG>(device) << std::endl;
    }

    uint32_t samples = 16*256;
    cl::make_kernel<cl_uint,cl::Buffer> Pointless(cl::Kernel(program,"Pointless"));
    cl::Buffer device_samples(context,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,sizeof(cl_uint)*samples);
    Pointless(cl::EnqueueArgs(queue, cl::NDRange(16)), samples, device_samples).wait();

    std::vector<cl_uint> host_samples(samples);
    queue.enqueueReadBuffer(device_samples,CL_TRUE,0,sizeof(cl_uint)*samples,host_samples.data());

    for (auto x: host_samples)
        std::cout << x;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Obviously I'm missing something very basic here.  They are both using the Intel ICD (I don't have an AMD device on this system).

Comment: Are all your opencl file versions match each other?

Comment: @huseyin There may be different versions of the ICD for the GPU and CPU, however I'm not sure that matters: if it were the ICD, wouldn't the GPU fail on both sets of code above?  Currently, it only fails with the first set of code.

Comment: @huseyin Both are using the same DLL: IntelOpenCL64.dll, version 1.0.1.1003.

Comment: Check the errors that return the OpenCL calls. Thats what they are for. Is the queue properly created? or Did the creation fail?

Comment: @DarkZeros I'm using exception code for that. I removed it to simplify the example code (there is no error reported, scary enough).

Comment: @bhimberg: All your codes backed by 64-bit versions? Maybe there is a 32bit version too. Can you elaborate Device(int32_t platform, int32_t device) parameters?

Comment: Check if the device/platform/queue are NULL. This looks like one of those problems.

Comment: So I may have stumbled upon a bug in the cl.hpp wrapper. cl::Context context_; context_ = cl::Context(...); isn't properly assigning the underlying objects address. Both cl::Context context_ = cl::Context(...) and `cl::Context context_(...);' work fine, however.

I tested in both G++ 4.8.1 and MSVC 2010 with the same results in both. That it works fine with the CPU points to a bug in Intel's ICD, maybe.

@Sharpneli, DarkZeros Thanks for your help. I can't post this as an answer, though I think it qualifies?

Comment: You can answer your own question as long as it is a proper answer, and it helps possible future users with the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

(Just started posting so I cannot comment yet)

I tested your code using Nvidia implementation (used trough Intel ICD). C++ compiler was G++ 4.7.3. Both of your examples worked perfectly on the GPU, also on the Intel CPU that is available.

So the issue is almost certainly limited only at the Intel GPU implementation.

Answer (score 0):

So I may have stumbled upon a bug in the `cl.hpp` wrapper. `cl::Context context_; context_ = cl::Context(...);` isn't properly assigning the underlying objects address. Both `cl::Context context_ = cl::Context(...)` and `cl::Context context_(...);` work fine, however.

I tested in both G++ 4.8.1 and MSVC 2010 with the same results in both. That it works fine with the CPU points to a bug in Intel's ICD, maybe. Though the Khronos Group documentation on `cl::Context` states it 'implicitly retains' with a brief comment about the application being able to release the underlying object without the wrapper being aware.

Thanks Sharpneli, DarkZeros.